how to add new columns and add new value that match with value in row in python?
I have a table in the following format:
| Name       | Col1 | Col2 |
| Product 1  | x    | xx   |
...
| Product 5  | y    | y    |

I want to add new column name Col3 with specific values. For example, Product 1 corresponds to 100, Product 2 corresponds to 40,.. Product 5 corresponds to 1000.
My expected output is:
| Name       | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
| Product 1  | x    | xx   | 100
...
| Product 5  | y    | y    | 1000

My code is: df.loc[(df['Name']== 'Product 1'), 'Col3'] = 100
=> error: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc'
Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Your issue is not reproducible as is. For [mre] please post a constructor of your dataframe as the output of df.to_dict()

Just map from a dictionary

You are mapping from one set of values to another, and so a Dictionary can be used for the mapping:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Product 1', 'Product 2'],
                  'Col1': ['x', 'xx'],
                  'Col2': ['y', 'yy']
                  })

convert = {'Product 1': 100,  'Product 2': 1000}

df['Col3']= df['Name'].map(convert)

print(df)

gives:
        Name Col1 Col2  Col3
0  Product 1    x    y   100
1  Product 2   xx   yy  1000

The code will give a NaN value in Col3 if the Name entry is not in the Dictionary. Such values can if required be changed to some other default value.

I don't know how you built your dataframe but the code below works for me:
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Name':['Product 1','Product 5'],
            'Col1':['x','xx'],
            'Col2':['y','yy']
               })

df.loc[(df['Name'] == 'Product 1'), 'Col3'] = 100
df.loc[(df['Name'] == 'Product 5'), 'Col3'] = 1000

print(df)

Output:
        Name Col1 Col2    Col3
0  Product 1    x    y   100.0
1  Product 5   xx   yy  1000.0

Please provide your code and environment specs if it still doesn't work

thank you for your help. I have tried to run this code again and again. Sometimes it works, sometimes not
